# Need help determining correct filepaths for pip, kernels etc

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, libraries, filepath

I'm having a 'module not found' issue, and my problem research has pointed me toward possible filepath name issues. I need some help verifying that my filepaths are correctly aligned.

When I first set up Jupyter Notebook and Python on my computer, and I didn't understand virtualenv at all, I made a lot of errors which were later discovered when coming across the 'module not found' issue.

I thought I had gotten this sorted at a few months back, as I haven't had any problems since and have used pip multiple times since for loading new libraries.

### THE ERROR:

```
import tweepy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tweepy'
```

### CHECKING IN PYTHON NOTEBOOK:

```
import sys

print(sys.executable)

/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python

print(sys.path)

['', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python36.zip', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site-packages', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site- 
 packages/aeosa', 
'/Users/Moos/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.6/site- 
packages/IPython/extensions','/Users/Moos/.ipython'
]
```

---

### IN TERMINAL:

```
which pip

/Users/Moos/anaconda3/bin/pip


which pip3

/Users/Moos/anaconda3/bin/pip3


jupyter kernelspec list

Available kernels:
python2    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
python3    /usr/local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
```

Is there an issue with the kernelspec list? Should they be referencing the anaconda3 pathway?

Repeat: I do not have this problem with any other library.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a trivial suggestion but have you checked if the "tweepy" is actually available in your current environment?

To check this you can type the following in anaconda prompt: "conda list tweepy", otherwise you might use the anaconda navigator to perform the same check visually.

Comment: Available in the current env, as well as pip and pip3 list checks. Tried another new library again today, same problem. Really odd, b/c I thought I fixed this issue months back, when I encountered the same problems. Worked fine all this time until just the other day -- did nothing out of the ordinary.